# Characteristic function for algebraic (linear?) function

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to create matrix A[i,j,k] with the following elements:

A[i,j,k] = 0 if k+j-s-i =/= 0

A[i,j,k] = p[s] if k+j-s-i =0 ( p[s] is given vector )

This may be written by characteristic function as p[s]*ð(k+j-s-i) or by Kronecker delta function as p[s]*ð(0,k+j-s-i).
Is there any "build in" function in R which gives that - I mean is there "ð" built in?

Or do I have to wrote it by myself?

I suppose it would be very useful to have built function which returns 1 for f(x)=0 and 0 otherwise, at least for linear f(x)

Comment: there is no such function as it is so easy to make yourself, f(x)==0 gives 1 when f(x)=0 and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite this as

```
A[i,j,k] = p[k+j-i] if that exists, otherwise 0
```

which could then be implemented as

```
p <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

pfun <- function(x) {
  if (x < 1 | x > length(p)) {
    0
  } else {
    p[x]
  }
}

n <- 5
A <- array(0, c(n, n, n)) 

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    for (k in 1:n) {
      A[i,j,k] <- pfun(k+j-i)
    }
  }
}
```

There may be something more elegant than triply-nested for loops.

As for a the function you ask about, something as simple as

```
as.numeric(f(x)==0)
```

would work.

Comment: You can replace triple loop with `A <- array(apply(expand.grid(1:n, 1:n, 1:n), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) pfun(x[3]+x[2]-x[1]) ), c(n, n, n))` Not sure if elegant or not though :)

Comment: as.numeric(f(x) == 0) looks great!